# How can I efficiently write a fallback to grab an object from localstorage in the event of an axios promise failing?

Tags: vue.js, local-storage, axios

I am trying to create a progressive web app (I think).
I have bound a button in my markup to a method that gets an object from a last.fm api

I want to write a fallback in case there is no response from the API to grab the same object from a previously cached request.

However I noticed two things are wrong
1. The cacheTopArtists function isn't saving my object into my localstorage correctly.

```
    new Vue({
    el: '#LastFM',
    data() {
        return {
            myArtists: null
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        loadCachedTopArtists: {
            if (localStorage.cachedArtists) {
                this.myArtists = localStorage.cachedArtists;
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getTopArtists: function(e) {
            axios
                .get("https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?api_key=2c5c5c19e5d21ce9cf86b13712a1bbed&format=json&method=user.getTopArtists&user=El_Mayo&period=overall&limit=200")
                .then(response => (this.myArtists = response.data.topartists.artist))
                .catch(error => console.log(error))
            //if there is an error nothing should happen an this.myArtists is still equal to the localStorage.cachedArtists from line 31 (?);

        },
        cacheTopArtists: function(e) {
            localStorage.setItem('cachedArtists', JSON.stringify(this.myArtists));
        }
    },
    computed: {
        backgroundImage: function() {
            return (artist) => artist.image.find(size => size.size === 'large')['#text']
        }
    }
})
```

The cachedArtists key exists but is null. Even though i set myArtists : null i think the condition is still being met as the code I wrote inside  is displaying

2. I think this is having a knockon effect on my mounted() function which should fill my empty object with the localstorage version on page load

I have tried moving the getTopArtists method to the mounted() object so it runs on page load

I have also tried setItem without stringifying the myArtists object.

Here is the pen with the js and html
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GaEaKp

No error messages, except cachedArtists being null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st - why should `cacheTopArtists` save something if it is never called? It should be called after a successful request.

2nd - if you want "fallback" behavior on page load then you should put you cache-loading routines to `axios .get(...) .catch(...)` handler. And call `getTopArtists` inside your `mounted` hook.

But the most efficient way to do this is to implement an API module and use axios interceptors to achieve transparent caching in case of successful response and intercept fails and return caches.

https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors

Comment: Hi Ivan, thanks for the advice. You're right, I had tried to cacheartists immediately but it wouldn't let me cache the artists to localstorage right after

` .then(response => (this.myArtists = response.data.topartists.artist))`

but I can do more than one then() function